# Trying to get the date next month that is in the same week on the same day

Tags: php, datetime

I have a date, let's say i have the 21st of Feb. which is the 3rd Sunday in February. How would i get the 3rd Sunday of March?(which would be the 20th of March. I looked at a couple of Posts here, but i couldn't find any help for my particular request.

Comment: What would you expect in case when next month does not have Nth week? For example January this year had 5 Fridays, but February only 4.

Comment: thats an interesting question. i guess id just set it to the last friday in this month and not the 5th. Google calendar does that. everything that is above 4 is just titled the last friday of the month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
<?php
// $time = time();
$wd = date('D', $time); // day of week
$week = 7 * 24 * 3600;
$n = ($time - strtotime("first $wd of this month", $time)) / $week;
$ns = array('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'last');
$next = strtotime("{$ns[$n]} $wd of next month", $time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it mathematically,

```
echo date('m/d/y', (time() + 21 * 86400));
```

86400 is one day, so `21 * 86400` is 3 weeks plus the current date (feb 21) gives:

> 03/13/16

If you have a text string you could use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it to the timestamp.

**Update:**

To get the third sunday you could use a conditional and see if the date is less than 14, which I think would always make it less than 3 weeks into the month.

```
echo (date('d', (time() + 21 * 86400) < 14)) ? date('m/d/y', (time() + 28 * 86400)) : date('m/d/y', (time() + 21 * 86400));
```

Comment: ok but you i still dont know how to get the 3rd Sunday of march

Comment: Update posted for third sunday, not third week.

Comment: but the date i want to know is variable. i can't just use the same formula with every date can i

Comment: Swap `time()` with the variable and/or use `strtotime` if it isn't a timestamp.